# Chrome on Windows 10 Freezing on Script Execution, Works Perfectly on Mac

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

I have an issue I assumed was related to the Windows 10 April CU with Chrome freezing and BSOD, and may well be, but what I've noticed is that in Windows Chrome (v66 and v67dev) the main thread is blocked and frozen, and won't allow scrolling for example, even though other Windows and other panels of Chrome are functioning without being frozen.

The actual performance in Mac Chrome is comparable in terms of script execution, but scrolling is allowed and the main thread does not appear blocked.

This same code also works perfectly in Windows Edge and Firefox without the freezing behavior.

This particular app is written in Ember CLI, but appears to be Chrome and Windows specific.

[image: Windows 10 Chrome - JS Execution of long running script]

Comment: Can't help much without being able to test. Do you have a public URL or demo of this app?